# "string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE." error

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I upgrade android-studio from v3.3.2 to v3.4.0 and trying to rebuild the project, showing "string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE." error.

Comment: why is this a problem?